# Getting the error out of a prediction and a measurement

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, code-request

Well, I've the following problem. I need to plot the error that the data gives with the prediction. I've the following code:

```
Show[{Plot[
   0.5*((1/Sqrt[(1 - (2530253 f^2 \[Pi]^2)/12500000000)^2 + ((
             59 f \[Pi])/62500 - (2783 f^3 \[Pi]^3)/625000000000)^2])/
      Sqrt[2]), {f, 10, 32}], 
  ListPlot[{{10, 0.4471}, {15, 0.6430}, {20, 1.66965}, {21, 
     2.577}, {22, 4.5811}, {22.1, 4.7738}, {22.2, 4.91835}, {22.3, 
     4.9966}, {22.3505609997, 5.005}, {22.4, 4.9940}, {22.5,}, {22.6, 
     4.7640}, {22.7, 4.5625}, {22.8, 4.33145}, {22.9, 4.08285}, {23, 
     3.8312}, {25, 1.3533}, {27, 0.76625}, {30, 0.45355}}]}]
```

And the plot part is the prediction and the listplot are the data points that I found by measuring on a system. Now how can I write a code that gives the plot of the error between the prediction and the measurement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting

```
data = {{10, 0.4471}, {15, 0.6430}, {20, 1.66965}, {21, 2.577}, {22, 4.5811},
        {22.1, 4.7738}, {22.2, 4.91835}, {22.3, 4.9966}, {22.3505609997, 5.005},
        {22.4, 4.9940}, {22.5,}, {22.6, 4.7640}, {22.7, 4.5625}, {22.8, 4.33145},
        {22.9, 4.08285}, {23, 3.8312}, {25, 1.3533}, {27, 0.76625}, {30, 0.45355}};
```

(note the missing value corresponding to `22.5`)

and

```
jopi[f_] := 0.5*((1/Sqrt[(1 - (2530253 f^2 π^2)/12500000000)^2 +
                ((59 f π)/62500 - (2783 f^3 π^3)/625000000000)^2])/Sqrt[2])
```

here is one way to plot your model, data, and residuals:

```
{Show[{Plot[jopi[f], {f, 10, 32}], ListPlot[data]}, PlotLabel -> "Data and Model"], 
 ListPlot[#2 - jopi[#1] & @@@ data,
          Filling -> Axis, PlotLabel -> "Residuals"]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: plot]

where `ListPlot[]` automagically filtered out the bad point.

Comment: Where are the @@@ signs for?

Comment: To give you a tip: anytime you encounter an unfamiliar symbol like `@@@` in any code you see in *Mathematica*, highlight it and press F1. In this case, it should take you to the documentation for `Apply[]`.

Answer (score 2):

@J.M. has already answered your question but if you're looking for a better prediction, you might consider the following fit using the same model structure but just with different coefficients:

```
data = {{10, 0.4471}, {15, 0.6430}, {20, 1.66965}, {21, 2.577}, {22, 4.5811},
   {22.1, 4.7738}, {22.2, 4.91835}, {22.3, 4.9966}, {22.3505609997, 5.005},
   {22.4, 4.9940}, {22.6, 4.7640}, {22.7, 4.5625}, {22.8, 4.33145},
   {22.9, 4.08285}, {23, 3.8312}, {25, 1.3533}, {27, 0.76625}, {30, 0.45355}};

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
   a1/Sqrt[(1 - a2 f^2)^2 + (a3 f - a4 f^3)^2],
   {{a1, 0.35}, {a2, 0.002}, {a3, 0.003}, {a4, 1.4 10^(-7)}}, f];

nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a1 -> 0.352095, a2 -> 0.00199721, a3 -> 0.00314666, a4 -> -1.0251*10^-14} *)

{Show[{Plot[nlm[f], {f, 10, 32}], ListPlot[data]}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Data and Model"],
  ListPlot[Transpose[{nlm["PredictedResponse"], nlm["FitResiduals"]}],
   Filling -> Axis, PlotLabel -> "Residuals", 
   AxesLabel -> {"Prediction", "Residual"}]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: Data, fit, and residuals]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.